# How to rename packages and classes programmically?

Tags: java, maven, automation, refactoring

I have a code base scattered across tens of repositories.

I want to standardize names of packages and classes, but it's too tedious to do it by hand in IDE, since I need a dictionary based renaming across repositories.

Is there a way **programmatically** rename classes and packages across many repositories?

A similar thing for a different language: https://metacpan.org/pod/App::EditorTools

Comment: What exactly do you expect? In Eclipse, you can copy/paste classes between packages and all references are updated automatically. The same with renaming classes.

Comment: Use the force Luke ... sorry Use your IDE ...is the best suggestion I give cause implementing something programmatically will be hard to develop to fix all the imports etc. maybe service loaders etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise Doing it in IDE is what I meant by hand. I have 17 repositories, and want to do a dictionary based renaming, and package restructing. It would take many hours going only with IDE

Comment: Rename the packages is not enough. You have to change all imports... also configurations etc. which is done by the IDE... Ok 17 repos how many code? Number of classes? Ok.. a number of hours? Of course...but implementing and testing a tool takes also hours... in IDE you have already checked compiling etc. ? I'm not sure that implementing a tool would be faster than doing by hand via IDE...???...

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse, and just about every other major IDE, can do this rather trivially. Load the project into the IDE (most can read the project if it is built by maven or gradle, just by saying you want to 'import an existing maven java project' or some such, possibly after installation a maven and/or gradle plugin - if it's not a project built by such tools, then just import an existing java project and tell eclipse about where the source files live).

Then, right click the package, pick refactor/rename, rename it, and eclipse (or intellij, or any other major java IDE) will rename the directory, update the package statement in every source file inside it, and will update all imports or any other reference, and will even search for strings that contain that exact name in case you're doing weird reflective shenanigans and tell you that those probably also need to be updated.

It's not quite programmatic, but this sounds like it'll be much easier and faster than actually using e.g. ecj or writing an eclipse app that will run without a user interface to apply these refactor scripts.